# how to disable lazy evaluation in Groovy closure

Tags: groovy, closures

My code is :

```
def ip_list = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3' ]
def task = [:]
for (ip in ip_list) {
   task[ip] = { println "test on ${ip}" }
}

for (f in task.values())
{
   f()
 }
```

The out put is :

```
test on 192.168.1.3
test on 192.168.1.3
test on 192.168.1.3
```

But which output I expect is :

```
test on 192.168.1.1
test on 192.168.1.2
test on 192.168.1.3
```

What should I do ?

Thanks!

Comment: why it's not like this: `for (ip in ip_list) { println "test on $ip" }`

Comment: In fact, I want to run every work in task  parallelly  in Jenkins pipeline later.

Answer (score 2):

#1

```
def ip_list = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3' ]
def task = [:]
for (_ip in ip_list) {
   def ip = _ip
   task[ip] = { println "test on ${ip}" }
}

for (f in task.values())
{
   f()
}
```

#2

```
def ip_list = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3' ]
def task = [:]
for (_ip in ip_list) {
   task[_ip] = {ip-> println "test on ${ip}" }.curry(_ip)
}

for (f in task.values()){
   f()
}
```

#3

```
def ip_list = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3' ]
def task = {ip-> println "test on ${ip}" }
def task_map = ip_list.collectEntries{ip-> [ip, task.curry(ip)] }

for (f in task_map.values()){
   f()
}
```

Comment: Bingo! That is what I want!  Thanks!